# Mongo: save an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save an array of objects to my mongo db in one save. I'd like to store each new object into a temporary array first, then send it to the server.js via an ajax post request. But each time it gets to the server, the data becomes just one giant object, and not an array of objects. Is what I'm trying to do possible with Mongo, or am I missing something? Here's my code below.

SCHEMA

```
    var capsuleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    qa: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question',
        question: String,
        answer: String
    }],
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    date_of_return: Date,
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

    var Capsule = mongoose.model('Capsule', capsuleSchema);
    module.exports = Capsule;
```

APP.JS

```
    var temp_id = id;
    var temp_q = quest;
    var temp_ans = $('#response').val();

    var tempQA = {
      id: temp_id,
      question: temp_q,
      answer: temp_ans
    };

    saveQuestion(tempQA);

    var saveQuestion = function(tempQA) {
      answeredQuestions.push(tempQA);
    }
    var capsuleData = {
        questions: answeredQuestions
    }

    newCapsule(capsuleData);

    var newCapsule = function(capsuleData) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/capsules",
            method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
            data: capsuleData
        }).done(function(data){
        // returns "capsule creation complete"
        });
    }; // end newCapsule
```

SERVER.JS

```
app.post('/capsules', function(req, res) {
  var qa_array = [];

  var capsule = new Capsule({
    qa: req.body.questions,
    user: req.cookies.loggedinId,
  });

  capsule.qa.push(req.body)

  capsule.save( function(err, capsule) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.statusCode = 503;
    } else {
      res.send(capsule);
    }; // end if/else
  }); // end save
}); // end post time-capsule
```

**UPDATE:**
I accidentally put the newCapsule(capsuleData) in the capsule object.--fixed.

I think the problem is in the ajax request. When the Array of objects goes through and gets to the server.js it gets reformatted into and array of one object containing array-innumerated, key:value pairs as strings even before I do anything with it on the server side. ("ie: 'questions[0][id]' : '12345', 'questions[0][question]' : 'how are you?'" etc.

I need it to stay as an array of objects though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save multiple documents, try `db.collection.insert`

[Check it out](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is not syntactically correct. `capsuleData` isn't a function its an object literal.

```
var capsuleData = { questions: answeredQuestions newCapsule(capsuleData); }
```

The below code attaches a method to the object. You also need to include `Capsule()` as a javascript function that is accessible so `new Capsule()` can create the javascript object. But that is still creating an object and not an array. You need to create the array client side and then pass it to the server to be processed.

```
var capsuleData = { questions: answeredQuestions,
anObjectMethod : new Capsule(capsuleData); }
```

Review this for more in-depth help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript